# Why does my profile picture look stretched after uploading?

Tags: bug, profile-page, profile-picture

Browser: Google Chrome Version 87.0.4280.141 (Official Build) (64-bit)

It seems like my profile picture looks stretched everywhere on every Stack Exchange website. The only place it's not stretched is in the navbar:

[image: Navbar, picture is not stretched]

However, on my Stack Overflow profile page it is stretched:

[image: Stretched image on Stack Overflow]

What gives? The dimensions of my image are 2301 x 2593 and it appears fine when I upload it on other websites. I think this may be a bug.

Comment: Crop it 1:1 ratio.

Comment: It is "only" stretched by 13%? Or more?